# JavaFx: Scroll reset after TitledPane is collapsed

Tags: java, javafx, scroll, tableview, javafx-8

I am using `TitledPane`s `ScrollPane`s and `TableView`s and I have the problem, when I collapse a titledPane, the horizontal `ScrollBar` of the `TableView` resets.

Here is a code example where you can verify it:

```
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class Controller implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane content;
    @FXML
    private TitledPane titledPane;
    @FXML
    private TableView<Object> tableView;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        titledPane.prefHeightProperty().bind(content.heightProperty());
        tableView.prefWidthProperty().bind(content.widthProperty());

        tableView.getColumns().forEach(col -> col.setPrefWidth(300)); // to have enough "space" to scroll

        tableView.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(new Object()));
    }

}
```

FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"
            xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
            fx:controller="stackoverflow.testscroll.Controller"
            fx:id="content">
            <TitledPane fx:id="titledPane">
                <TableView fx:id="tableView">
                    <columns>
                        <TableColumn/>
                        <TableColumn/>
                        <TableColumn/>
                        <TableColumn/>
                        <TableColumn/>
                        <TableColumn/>
                        <TableColumn/>
                        <TableColumn/>
                    </columns>
                </TableView>
           </TitledPane>
</AnchorPane>
```

Any idea how can I prevent the scroll of the tableview to reset every time I collapse the pane?

Comment: hmm ... don't quite understand why you have the scrollPane around the titledPane? why isn't the implicit scrollPane of the table good enough?

Comment: That can be ignored, I just copied my code, to a dummy project. In the original I have many `TitledPane`s in a `ScrollPane` that's why it is there, but I remove it, to be more simple.

Comment: just noticed that it doesn't matter - the implicit scrollPane is reset to 0 as well ... could be a bug: would expect the titledPane to restore to the exact state before collapsing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit of digging, it looks like some layout optimization in VirtualFlow might be the reason (all seems to be fine if the scrolled content is not a TableView - not thoroughly analyzed, though)

What happens is:

- during collapse, the TitledPane's content is resized vertically to 0
- in VirtualFlow's layoutChildren a zero height/width is special cased to do nothing except hide everything, including the scrollBars
- an internal listener to the scrollBar's visiblilty resets its value to 0

A tentative (read: dirty and might have unwanted side-effects, totally untested beyond this quick outline!) hack around is a custom TableViewSkin that tries to "remember" the last not-zero value and resets it on getting visible again.

An example:

```
public class TitledPaneTableScroll extends Application {

    public static class TableViewScrollSkin<T> extends TableViewSkin<T> {

        DoubleProperty hvalue = new SimpleDoubleProperty();

         public TableViewScrollSkin(TableView<T> control) {
            super(control);
            installHBarTweak();
        }

        private void installHBarTweak() {
            // Note: flow and bar could be legally retrieved via lookup 
            // protected api pre-fx9 and post-fx9
            VirtualFlow<?> flow = getVirtualFlow();
            // access scrollBar via reflection 
            // this is my personal reflective access utility method - use your own :)
            ScrollBar bar = (ScrollBar) FXUtils
                    .invokeGetFieldValue(VirtualFlow.class, flow, "hbar");
            bar.valueProperty().addListener((s, o, n) -> {
                if (n.intValue() != 0) {
                    hvalue.set(n.doubleValue());
                    // debugging
                    //  new RuntimeException("who is calling? \n").printStackTrace();
                } 
                //LOG.info("hbar value: " + n + "visible? " + bar.isVisible());
            });

            bar.visibleProperty().addListener((s, o, n) -> {
                if (n) {
                    bar.setValue(hvalue.get());
                } 
            });
        }
    }

    int counter;
    private Parent createContent() {

        TableView<Object> table = new TableView<>(FXCollections.observableArrayList(new Object()) ) {

            @Override
            protected Skin<?> createDefaultSkin() {
                return new TableViewScrollSkin<>(this);
            }

        };
        table.getColumns().addAll(Stream
                .generate(TableColumn::new)
                .limit(10)
                .map(col -> {
                    col.setPrefWidth(50);
                    col.setText("" + counter++);
                    return col;
                })
                .collect(Collectors.toList())); 


        TitledPane titled = new TitledPane("title", table);
        titled.setAnimated(true);

        BorderPane content = new BorderPane(titled);
        return content;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.setScene(new Scene(createContent(), 400, 400));
       // stage.setTitle(FXUtils.version());
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger
            .getLogger(TitledPaneTableScroll.class.getName());

}
```

Comment: Which version of Java(Fx) are you using? I don't have FXUtils for example.

Comment: that's just a utility class for  reflective access - simply use your own or use node.lookup :)

Comment: Ahh okay,it worked using `queryAA`. Considering it is more or less a hack, I have to test it well to ensure it doesn't cause any unexpected bug, but anyways it is a solution, thanks ;)

Comment: definitely a hack - and totally untested as well :) Good luck!

Comment: If you scroll hard to the beginning of the TV sometimes it freezes because of the 0 check :) Scrolling smoothly I can scroll to near 0 :)

Comment: I modified it setting the value only when it is getting visible, and it works ;)

Comment: cool - please feel free to edit my answer with your improvement :)

Comment: after testing a lot, and trying to solve it without using this set/reset mechanism, I noticed that at collapse sometimes it doesn't call the setHValue at all and it works fine, but in another view it calls and messes up some scrollbar synchronizations. Do you have any idea when it is called exactly and when it is not?

Comment: Setting a min height helped after a lot of debugging and looking for differences...

Comment: sry no idea, just looked for the differences between a plain scrollPane and virtualflow .. as you did ;)